# Do I need to quarantine If I'm travelling to Scotland from Ireland?

Tags: covid-19, ireland, scotland

I would like to travel to Edinburgh from Dublin for a weekend holiday at the end of this month or the start of January.

I have already gotten the COVID-19 vaccination and have the proof in a .pdf document. Is this all I need to travel or do I also need another antigen test?

Answer (score 2):

Travel within the UK, and to the Republic of Ireland, Isle of Man, Jersey and Guernsey, is not counted as international travel. This means that you do not need to test, isolate or fill in a passenger locator form if:

- you’re travelling to Scotland from England, Wales, Northern Ireland, Republic of Ireland, Isle of Man, Jersey or Guernsey
- you have not travelled anywhere other than these areas in the 10 days before you arrive in Scotland.

Source: https://www.gov.scot/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-guidance-on-travel-and-transport/

You should be aware that you may need to show a QR code to prove your vaccination status in some venues. Restrictions in Scotland are changing in response to Omicron, for example  today it was announced that from 11 Dec all household contacts of any confirmed Covid case must isolate for 10 days regardless of their vaccination status and even if they initially get a negative PCR test. The situation at the end of the month may be worse.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes for your return trip.

The Republic of Ireland does count travel from the UK to the Republic of Ireland as international travel and all arrivals at Dublin are subject to immigration checks.

As of today (24 December 2021) travellers arriving in Dublin from outside the island of Ireland must have:

- a completed of a [Irish passenger locator form](https://www.gov.ie/en/publication/ab900-covid-19-passenger-locator-form/), and
- for unvaccinated travellers: a not-detected PCR test taken no more than 72 hours before arrival,
- for vaccinated travellers: a not-detected PCR test taken no more than 72 hours before arrival, or a not-detected, professionally performed anti-gen test taken no more than 48 hours before arrival.

There is currently no requirement to quarantine.

Certain exceptions do apply, see https://www.gov.ie/en/publication/77952-government-advice-on-international-travel/ for full details.

Note that restrictions are fluid and likely to change without notice.

Comment: Does this also apply if OP first goes to Northern Ireland and then crosses overland? Who would they show their test result if crossing that way?

Comment: @MJ Walsh, when they say that the PCR test should be performed no more than 72 hours, does that mean that I can take a test up to an hour before I depart the UK back to Ireland?

Comment: @EricHernandez Yes, assuming you can get a result that quickly.